# Airflow can't Decrypt connections from a 'follower' server

Tags: encryption, celery, airflow

I have installed Airflow in multiple machines using CeleryExecuter: the main machine runs the scheduler, web-server and one worker and two follower machines run two celeried workers.

Everything works fine but Celery worker in a follower Airflow machine can't decrypt connection that was created in the main Airflow machine.

I have used the same ariflow.cfg in every machine, hence the same farnet_key and the same database and everything.

Still the follower workers cant decrypt the connection that was created in the main machine, has anybody had the same issue before? any solutions?

Thanks for any help.